# Interesting Language Differences

Tags: discusión

Would a question asking about interesting language differences be appropriate? My favorite is "Me perdi al autobus" for I missed the bus in English. The literal translation: the bus was lost to me implies it was more the bus's fault than it was mine. Another I read recently was 
"mata a tiro", which I take to mean kill shot or fatal shot.

There wouldn't be a right answer. I just thought it would make for interest reading.

Comment: Uhms, I think it could be interesting. However, the format of the site is Q&A and it would be difficult to know which is *the* answer. You should probably narrow it down to: "does the expression X have a meaningful meaning in Y?".

Comment: This is a fascinating topic for discussion.  I love the way English and Spanish express the same thought in very different ways.  With regard  to "me perdí", my favorite is "se cayó".  It just fell.  I had nothing to do with it.  The problem with your suggestion comes from the fact that it just doesn't fit into the Q & A format favored in all the SE areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. From the [On topic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics. They are out of scope for this site.
>
> - ...
> - "List" questions, where every answer is equally valid

From the [Don't ask](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.